# How to connect Mongodb Atlas to Spring

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-atlas

I have a web application which is using Spring Boot to handle the backend logics. I'm trying to integrate mongodb to track some information about the users of this webapp.
I created a database on mongodb Atlas and through the Mongo Shell the connection goes fine. The problem comes when I try to connect with Spring. Let me show you all the details

Inside Atlas, I added this IP Address (0.0.0.0/0  (includes your current IP address)) into Security > Network Address. In theory this should allow me to connect to the database from any IP address.

I then created a collection called "test".

If I click on my cluster and then on the connect button, it ask me with which modality I want to connect. I choose "Connect your application", and then I have to select the Driver and the Version. I choose respectively "Java" and "3.6 or later" (I'm not sure if it's the correct version, the alternatives are 3.4 or 3.3). And finally it shows me the connection string which is:

```
mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@umadit-obxpb.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

To connect to Atlas with Spring I'm using this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Inside the application.properties file I have these two lines to configure mongo.

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@umadit-obxpb.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

Instead of the password I put  for obvious reasons.

The only problem is that when I start Spring Boot I continue to receive this error message:

```
2020-02-25 16:31:25.605  INFO 41162 --- [=majority:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@umadit-obxpb.mongodb.net/test?retrywrites=true&w=majority:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@umadit-obxpb.mongodb.net/test?retrywrites=true&w=majority: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddress(ServerAddress.java:188) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:59) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:57) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:114) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@umadit-obxpb.mongodb.net/test?retrywrites=true&w=majority: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddress(ServerAddress.java:186) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.6.4.jar:na]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

I don't know what to do in order to make it work. Am I missing something?

**SOLUTION**

As @barrypicker suggested, the problem was inside the properties file. Instead of using spring.data.mongodb.host I used spring.data.mongodb.uri. Now it works perfectly.

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@umadit-obxpb.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

even without spring.data.mongodb.port

Comment: Well the error indicates hostname is unknown.  Did you run your mongo shell test on the same computer you are running this spring app?  Seems like a DNS problem on the surface...

Comment: @barrypicker yes I did!

Comment: Not exactly sure - I cannot find the documentation, but instead of `spring.data.mongodb.host` try `spring.data.mongodb.uri`

Comment: ... I think you need to use the port number in the URI as well...

Comment: Thank you @barrypicker! It worked with spring.data.mongodb.uri! Trying to check if it was a more complex problem I didn't even think about that!

Comment: Awesome! Good Job!

Comment: thank you @barrypicker

i have replaced the connection string with this one and it works 

    spring.data.mongodb.uri=  spring.data.mongodb.host=mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@umadit-obxpb.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Comment: @barrypicker @Stefano  Do you need to use `@Configuration` annotation and configure even after mentioning the connection string in the application properties file?

Comment: @Srs - The @Configuration annotation is to load spring dependencies such as `@Autowire`.  This annotation allows you to specify your configuration file.  This is a Spring option in the event you opt to use an external file instead of a Java class.  The Strategy by Stefano was to utilize an external file instead of a Java class.  When this happens you will need to specify the file using `@Configuration`.  At some point in your application lifecycle you will need to define the spring application context.

Comment: @StefanoSambruna I used spring.data.mongodb.uri. But, I am still facing the problem

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think your to connect to Mongo Atlas your application.properties should have spring.data.mongodb.uri instead of spring.data.mongodb.host.`spring.data.mongodb.uri: mongodb://<user>:<passwd>@<host>:<port>/<dbname>`
I think this may work
`

Answer (score 1):

Use this dependency inside "pom.xml" file

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Inside the "application.properties"

use "spring.data.mongodb.uri"

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@<cluster_name>.mogodb.net/<dbname>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another issue with the atlas is that your IP is not allowed, make sure you add your IP at the network access tab.
[image]