# Unable to specify username and password for MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm attempting to amend: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-tutorial to connect to MongoDB Atlas cloud instance (https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas)

Here is the local DB connection:

<mongo:mongo-client id="mongoClient" host="localhost" />

I'm attempting to change it to:

```
<mongo:mongo-client host="cluster.test.mongodb.net/" port="27017" id="mongoClient" credentials="dbUser:password****@mydb">
</mongo:mongo-client>
```

but I receive error: "Attribute credentials is not allowed here"

Where and how should I define the attribute credentials?

I'm using MongoDB driver version `4.0.5`

entire mongoConfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    
    <mongo:mongo-client host="cluster.test.mongodb.net/" port="27017" id="mongoClient" credentials="dbUser:password****@mydb">
    </mongo:mongo-client>

    <mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="test" mongo-client-ref="mongoClient" />

    <bean id="gridFsTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.gridfs.GridFsTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoConverter" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoConverter" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <mongo:repositories base-package="com.baeldung.repository" mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate" />

    <bean class="com.baeldung.event.CascadeSaveMongoEventListener">
    </bean>

    <mongo:mapping-converter id="mongoConverter" base-package="com.baeldung.converter">
        <mongo:custom-converters base-package="com.baeldung.converter" />
    </mongo:mapping-converter>

</beans>
```

I followed this https://developpaper.com/notes-for-spring-xml-mongodb-connection-configuration-specifying-user-name-and-password/ tutorial where is defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">

    <mongo:mongo-client host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}" id="mongoClient" credentials="${mongo.username}:${mongo.password}@${mongo.dbname}">
    </mongo:mongo-client>
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="${mongo.dbname}" mongo-ref="mongoClient" id="mongoDbFactory" />
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: And how is this related to Spring Boot? But to answer use `credential` instead of `credentials`. You are following an outdated tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

From this fixed the issue:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@umadit-obxpb.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

From question: [How to connect Mongodb Atlas to Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60398285/how-to-connect-mongodb-atlas-to-spring)

I used application.properties instead of XML config to connect.